# How can I improve this VBA code copying data from one sheet to another and saving the changes? Multiple user performing same time

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

How can I improve this VBA code copying data from one sheet to another and saving the changes?

In below Code For Login workbook to copying data to Another master workbook but here 65 people using this Login workbook.

So i setting  loop for read only in. once master workbook read only false then another user data saving in master workbook

Now what is the issue we are facing user not waiting for the that loop time they r trying to force close the excel that time master workbook stuck in read only mode in that user name. that time other user stuck in loop period.

Sometimes getting run time error also like (380 invalid property value) & sometime destination workbook(master) opened for user

```
Sub RTS()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Scheduled Ad").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("GLOLOGIN")
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Copy & Paste the data from "Scheduled Ad" sheet to "RTS Report.Xlsb" Sheet
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A7:D7,Q7").Select
    Range("Q7").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    
    Range("A7").Select
    

    Dim wb      As Workbook
    Dim Path As String
    Dim File As String
        
    Path = Range("Y2").Value
    File = Range("AC2").Value
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "\" & File )
        
    Do Until wb.ReadOnly = False
        wb.Close
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "\" & File)
            
    Loop

    
    Dim She         As Worksheet
    Dim b           As Integer
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Day In").Activate
    Set She = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    b = She.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    She.Range("A" & b + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    wb.Close
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    
    ActiveSheet.Protect ("GLOLOGIN")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

I'm particularly interested in suggestions for refactoring and improving performance.

Comment: My main request Excel A is using 65 peoples to getting they login logout and break time ,
In shift end  they clicking Button all user Login logout , break time details need to saved in Excel B. when multiple users clicking button on same time got error plse help me for this

Comment: Excel B is single file ,only Leads have access to this excel to getting all user day wise data so who r all using Excel A that data need to be saved in here

Comment: It would be easier to have each user write their data to a separate file in a common location, and then combine those files using a separate code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BruceWayne While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ - Yes, agreed. I retracted my close vote almost immediately...though the comment still shows up.

Answer (score -1):

Excel is multi-users now.

*If you want several users to work in the same Excel workbook simultaneously, you can save the workbook as a shared workbook. Users can then enter data, insert rows and columns, add and change formulas, and change formatting.*

See this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/use-shared-workbook